# I can't create an outlet for a label in my collection view cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview, outlet

So everything is done the way you would assume. I drag and drop a collection view into a controller view. I connect the datasource and delegate. blah blah blah everything is done by the book.

Ok so i want to connect a label inside my collectionViewCell to my viewController class. I use control+drag to drop it into my code and type in its name.

As soon as i hit connect, i get a red octagonal error. it says: "Illegal Configuration: The hoursPerDayOutlet outlet from the monthCellViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."

I need to connect this though because as each cell is created it will have a different label.

Please help me fix and use swift. All advice is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't connect items inside a `UICollectionViewCell` to a `UIViewController`, create a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, make the class of the cell to the subclass and then you can connect the items inside the cell to the subclass (not the controller). I recommend you to look at more [tutorials on `UICollectionView`](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer, after creating a UICollectionViewCell subclass and verifying that the class of that cell is subclassed, you have to make sure that your `UIViewController` that you were originally trying to connect the outlet to is a `UICollectionViewDelegate` subclass.

After that you should be able to successfully create an outlet for your label, etc.